# Photoshop: automatically make border smoother

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How can I make the border of shapes smoother, without re-touching it in detail ?

Is there any Photoshop advanced functionality doing it automatically ?

See example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/border.png

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gaussian blur of about 1.5 pixels might be what you need.

Comment: And to be really paranoid, mask it off first.

Answer (score 0):

Some blur, perhaps combined with median filtering. But typically this problem comes from a bad resampling or rasterizing (forgot to check "antialiasing?"), and then it's a little too late to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Your only hope there is to re-draw it.